# can't edit .bashrc while it is already present in the directory

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm setting up zsh in my Windows subsystem for Linux in my windows 10 machine by following some tutorial which instructs on opening my bash profile by the following command

```
vim~/.bashrc
```

but it says

```
bash: vim~/.bashrc: No such file or directory
```

I've tried using

```
ls -la ~/ | more
```

which shows the file is present, even tried copying it from the /etc/skel but still no luck

Comment: Chuckling.... yes, always, a space between the command and each of the arguments (and double-quote arguments that contain whitespace like `"this file"`)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try the below command

vi ~/.bashrc

Answer (score -1):

Yeah I was running the command incorrectly it required a space as suggested by @john1024 but running either of the commands

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

and

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

gave me a warning that the file is already open with something like a bashrc.swap file ... Eventually made my edits and saved. Thanks for the quick support. (y)

Comment: Note original `vi` and `vim` (vi - improved) are very different versions of the same editor (on some system `vi` is just a symlink to `vim`). However, if you notice differences, that is the reason. Both create a swap file `file.swp` during editing. If you kill the editor before you exit (using `:q` to quit or `:wq` to save and quit), then you will leave the `.swp` on your system and you will be prompted what to do with it the next time you edit that file.